# How to increase the horizontal spacing around `=&' in the align environment?

Tags: spacing, align, horizontal

I found it too squeezed around the operators when I use align for multiple lines of equations. See the example.

```
\begin{align*}
&a + b \\
=& c + d \\
=& e + f
\end{align*}
```

How to increase the space around `=' to make something like

```
\begin{align*}
&a + b \\
= \ & c + d \\
= \ & e + f
\end{align*}
```

Comment: `={}&` is the right way.

Comment: Yes, that works. But I have to add {} for each line. Is there a command for the whole document?

Comment: You shouldn't be using such a layout to begin with.

Comment: If you want to do a "waterfall" like effect, see the `\MoveEqLeft` macro from mathtools

Answer (score 3):

You need `={}&` or the space after `=` will not be correct.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools} % also loads amsmath

\begin{document}

This is a wrong display
\begin{align*}
&a + b \\
=& c + d \\
=& e + f
\end{align*}
This is a bit better
\begin{align*}
&a + b \\
={}& c + d \\
={}& e + f
\end{align*}
but the following is even better
\begin{align*}
\MoveEqLeft[1] a + b \\
&= c + d \\
&= e + f
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I'd use such a layout only in case the top expression is very long; otherwise

```
\begin{align*}
a + b
  &= c + d \\
  &= e + f
\end{align*}
```

is the way to go.